# filter .x before passing to function ~

Tags: r, purrr

I have a snippet within a purrr and dplyr chain:

```
MAPE180 = map_dbl(TestData, ~Metrics::mape(.x %>% filter(TENURE == 180) %>% pull(CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT), 
                                           .x %>% filter(TENURE == 180) %>% pull(Prediction)))
```

This works fine. I wanted to remove the duplication of `.x %>% filter(TENURE == 180)` and tried this hoping for equivalent:

```
MAPE180 = map_dbl(TestData %>% filter(TENURE == 180), ~Metrics::mape(.x$CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT, .x$Prediction))
```

But this gives error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `MAPE180`.
ℹ `MAPE180 = map_dbl(...)`.
x no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "list"
```

How can I filter my `.x` before passing to tilde `~`?

Comment: It is a `list` of data.frame i.e. `TestData`.  Then, you can't `filter` on a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error showed, it is `filter` applied on a `list`, which doesn't work.  Instead, do the `filter` on each element of the `list` once, instead of twice

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dbl(TestData, ~ {
          tmp <- .x %>% 
                filter(TENURE == 180) # do filter once
          Metrics::mape(tmp %>% 
                          pull(CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT), 
                                           tmp %>% 
                          pull(Prediction))
    })
```

In addition, this can be also done within `summarise`

```
map_dfr(TestData, ~ .x %>%
                filter(TENURE == 180) %>%
                summarise(MAPE = Metrics::mape(CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT, 
                     Prediction)))
```

Comment: Nice one on using summarise there! How/why does this work?

Comment: @DougFir it works because `mape` returns a single value (even for multiple values, `summarise` now works.  Therefore, you can return as a tibble/data.frame instead of  extracting as a vector